# To check a date in one table does NOT exist in reservation period in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, not-exists

I am new to this after spending 2 days trying to find an answer on the net
I am trying to construct a MYSQL select statement

I have 2 tables on ethat contains a list of dates and prices, the second is a table of reservation dates with start and end. I am tring to show al the FREE dates & prices in Table 1 that DO NOT exist in any of the reservation records in Table 2

Table 1 called - **dates_prices** -
id,  date,   price

example data

```
333, 2011-12-20, 66.00
333, 2011-12-21, 66.00
333, 2011-12-22, 66.00
333, 2011-12-23, 66.00
333, 2011-12-24, 66.00
333, 2011-12-25, 66.00
333, 2011-12-26, 66.00
333, 2011-12-27, 66.00
333, 2011-12-28, 66.00
333, 2011-12-29, 66.00
333, 2011-12-30, 66.00
```

Table 2 - **reservations**

**id,  startdate,  enddate**

example data

```
333, 2011-12-20, 2011-12-22
333, 2011-12-24, 2011-12-26
333, 2011-12-28, 2011-12-30
```

I need to extract ONLY the dates from Table 1 that do not exist in the Table 2 records between start and end dates of all records in table 2 with the same ID number 333

So the only records that should  be displayed from table 1 are as follows

**id,      date,     price**

```
333, 2011-12-23, 66.00
333, 2011-12-27, 66.00
333, 2011-12-31, 66.00
```

Comment: You forgot the entry "333, 2011-12-30, 66.00" in dates_prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table  table12 (id int, datefor date, price int)

insert  into  table12
select 333, '2011-12-20', 66.00
union all
select 333, '2011-12-21', 66.00
union all
 select 333, '2011-12-22', 66.00
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-23', 66.00
 union all
select 333, '2011-12-24', 66.00
union all
 select 333, '2011-12-25', 66.00
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-26', 66.00
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-27', 66.00
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-28', 66.00
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-29', 66.00
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-30', 66.00 

 create table  table2 (id int, startdate date, enddate date)

insert  into  table2
select 333, '2011-12-20', '2011-12-22'
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-24', '2011-12-26'
 union all
 select 333, '2011-12-28', '2011-12-30'
```

try this after creating above tables. solution to ur probelm is u need to make this type of query to tables ie
select * from  table12 where  datefor not between '2011-12-20' and '2011-12-22' and   datefor not between '2011-12-24' and '2011-12-26' and   datefor not between '2011-12-28' and '2011-12-30' and  table12.id=333 i have made one proc just u need to pass ur id.

```
create proc solution( @id int) 
  as
  begin

declare @count int
    declare @i int
    declare @query varchar(800)
    set @query=''
 declare @startdate varchar(80)
    set @startdate=''
     declare @enddate varchar(80)
    set @enddate=''

 declare @table table( row int ,startdate date,enddate date,id int)
insert into @table select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rownumber  ,startdate,enddate,id  from  table2  where table2.id=@id
 set  @count=(select COUNT (*)  from  @table )
 set   @i=1
 set @query += 'select * from  table12 where '
while @count>=@i
begin
 set @startdate=( select startdate  from  @table  where row=@i) 
 set  @enddate =(select enddate  from  @table  where row=@i)
 set @query +=  ' datefor not between '+''''+@startdate+''''+ ' and '+'''' +@enddate+''''
 if   @count>@i
 begin
 set @query +=' and  '
 end
 if @count=@i
 begin
 set @query += ' and  table12.id='+cast (@id as varchar(50)) +''
 end 

set @i+=1
 end
 if(@i=1)
 set @query+='table12.id='+cast (@id as varchar(50)) +''


  exec (@query)
end

exec solution 333
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the query to exclude dates.

```
select dp.id, dp.date, dp.price
  from dates_prices dp
   left join 
     (select dp.id, dp.date
       from dates_prices dp
       join reservations res 
        on res.id = dp.id 
         and dp.date between res.startdate and res.enddate) as inner_table
     on inner_table.id = dp.id and inner_table.date = dp.date
   where inner_table.id is null
```

Comment: @greyfairer - I just reconstructed his tables and data on my machine, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p1.* FROM dates_prices p1 
WHERE (p1.id, p1.date) NOT IN
(
  SELECT p2.id, p2.date
  FROM dates_prices p2
  JOIN reservations r
  ON  (
     r.id = p2.id 
     and r.startdate <= p2.date 
     and p2.date <= r.enddate
  )
)
```

Comment: This query isn't returning the 12-29 entry for some reason

Comment: @BrianHoover it shouldn't: 12-29 is between 12-28 and 12-30 afaik

Comment: yeah, I just read the requirements again.  But then it's not returning the 12/31 entry.

Comment: I ran the previous version that Brian provided - very quick but did not work with multiple ranges in the reservations table - the version with the JOIN is very cpu intensive takes 2 minutes to complete - my tables have 80,000 entries in the dates_prices and my reservations has 850 entries

Comment: Edited: I forgot the p1.id. Can you try this one again? Maybe an index on  dates_prices(id, date) will help.

Comment: I created an index on dates_prices(id, date) call id_2 can I force this to be used - also if we pick an id such as 333 will this reduce the search

Answer (score 0):

This should work too, could be a lot faster:

```
SELECT p1.* FROM dates_prices p1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * FROM reservations r
  WHERE r.id = p1.id 
  AND r.startdate <= p1.date 
  AND p1.date <= r.enddate  
)
```